# Is there an equivalent to PIG.COMPILE for HIVE?

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, apache-pig

Using Pig/Python, I can easily perform

```
P = Pig.Compile(...)
```

Is there an equivalent for Hive?  So, I would imagine something like

```
P = Hive.Compile(...)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's on TODO list. See issue [HIVE-599](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-599).